# How to update multiple values with an array inside Reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the following code to update the `currentScore` of a `rubricItem` object. This works fine.

```
case SAVE_SCORELIST_SUCCESS:
    const scoreItem = action.payload.scoreItem;
    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        editing: false,
        rubricItems: {
            ...state.rubricItems,
            [scoreItem.rubricItemId]: {
                ...state.rubricItems[scoreItem.rubricItemId],
                currentScore: scoreItem.currentScore,
            }
        }
    };
```

However, I may receive an array object holding scores for multiple `rubricItems` instead of updating a single `rubricItem` with a single `scorItem` as I did above.

I know I can use `.map()` to iterate through the array:

```
scoreItems.map(si=>{})
```

But, I do not know how I can integrate it into this:

```
case SAVE_SCORELIST_SUCCESS:
    const scoreItems = action.payload.scoreItems;

    return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        editing: false,
        rubricItems: {
            ...state.rubricItems,
            [scoreItems[x].rubricItemId]: {
                ...state.rubricItems[scoreItems[x].rubricItemId],
                currentScore: scoreItems[x].currentScore,
            }
        }
    };
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Take out the logic of updating the item from the `rubricItems`. Apply a `forEach` or `map` on the payload. And then spread them together.

Comment: @UtsavPatel thank! How to do that : `take out the logic of updating the item from the rubricItems`? Any examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

First you need to iterate over scoreItems and make a `map` object of updated score items.

Once you have done that, you can use the `spread` operator with the current score items in state.

```
case SAVE_SCORELIST_SUCCESS:
let updatedScoreItems = {};
action.payload.scoreItem.forEach(scoreitem => {
  updatedScoreItems[scoreItem.rubricItemId] = {
    ...state.rubricItems[scoreItem.rubricItemId],
    currentScore: scoreItem.currentScore,
  }
})
return {
  ...state,
  loading: false,
  editing: false,
  rubricItems: {
    ...state.rubricItems,
    ...updatedScoreItems
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of mapping over `scoreItem`, map over the `rubricItems` which will be cleaner.

```js
const updatedRubricItems = items.rubricItems.map(rubricItem => {
    const scoreForRubric = scoreItems.find(si => si.rubricItemId === rubricItem.id);// i assume you have some id for your rubric item
    if(scoreForRubric){
        return {...rubricItem, currentScore: scoreForRubric.currentScore}
    }else {
        return rubricItem
    }
});

return {
  ...state,
  loading: false,
  editing: false,
  rubricItems: updatedRubricItems
};
```